# How to save check button of checked to localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add checked To-do to the local storage, so that when I refresh, the to-do stays checked?

```js
//? Selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');

//! Listeners
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getTodos);
todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener('click', deleteCheck);
filterOption.addEventListener('click', filterTodo);

//TODO Functions

function addTodo(event) {
  //Prevent from submitting
  event.preventDefault()
  //.Todo DIV
  const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
  todoDiv.classList.add('todo');
  //Creat LI
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerHTML = todoInput.value;
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
  //ADD TODO TO LOCALSTORAGE
  saveLocalTodos(todoInput.value);
  //CHECK MARK BUTTON
  const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
  completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
  completedButton.classList.add('completed-button');
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
  //CHECK TRASH BUTTON
  const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
  trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
  trashButton.classList.add('trash-button');
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
  //APPEND TO LIST
  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
  //Clear Todo INPUT VALUE
  todoInput.value = '';
}

function deleteCheck(e) {
  const item = e.target;
  //DELETE TODO
  if (item.classList[0] === 'trash-button') {
    const todo = item.parentElement;
    //Animation
    todo.classList.add("fall");
    removeLocalStorge(todo);
    todo.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
      todo.remove();
    });
  }

  //CHECK MARK
  if (item.classList[0] === "completed-button") {
    const todo = item.parentElement;
    todo.classList.toggle('completed');
  }
}

function filterTodo(event) {
  const todos = todoList.childNodes;
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    const mStyle = todo.style;
    if (mStyle != undefined && mStyle != null) {
      switch (event.target.value) {
        case 'all':
          todo.style.display = "flex";
          break;
        case "completed":
          if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
            todo.style.display = "flex";
          } else {
            todo.style.display = "none";
          }
          break;
        case "uncompleted":
          if (!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
            todo.style.display = "flex"
          } else {
            todo.style.display = "none";
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  });
}

function saveLocalTodos(todo) {
  //CHECK
  let todos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
    todos = [];
  } else {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
  }
  todos.push(todo);
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function getTodos() {
  let todos;

  if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
    todos = [];
  } else {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
  }

  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    todoDiv.classList.add('todo');
    //Creat LI
    const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
    newTodo.innerHTML = todo;
    newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
    todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
    //CHECK MARK BUTTON
    const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
    completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
    completedButton.classList.add('completed-button');
    todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
    //CHECK TRASH BUTTON
    const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
    trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
    trashButton.classList.add('trash-button');
    todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
    //APPEND TO LIST
    todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
  });
}

function removeLocalStorge(todo) {
  let todos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
    todos = [];
  } else {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
  }

  const todoIndex = todo.children[0].innerText;
  todos.splice(todos.indexOf(todoIndex), 1);
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365, #ff8e6f);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

header,
form {
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form input {
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

form button {
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

form input,
form button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: white;
}

form button {
  color: #ff8e6f;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

form button:hover {
  background-color: #ff8e6f;
  color: white;
}

.todo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.todo-list {
  min-width: 30%;
  list-style: none;
}

.todo {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.todo li {
  flex: 1;
}

.trash-button,
.completed-button {
  background: #ff6f47;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.trash-button {
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.completed-button {
  background: rgb(73, 204, 73);
}

.todo-item {
  padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
}

.fa-trash,
.fa-check {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.fall {
  transform: translateY(8rem) rotateZ(20deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.select {
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

select {
  color: #ff6f47;
  width: 10rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.select::after {
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  background: #ff6f47;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.select:hover::after {
  background: white;
  color: #ff6f47;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Todo-List</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Yamen's Todo List</h1>
  </header>
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="todo-input">
    <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="select">
      <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="todo-container">
    <ul class="todo-list">

    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? You have all the code you need. I made a snippet. It does not run here (sandbox issues with localStorage) but is easier to read.